# How can I make a selected image clickable with a link in my wordpress website

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a website on WordPress and I'm using a plug-in for tables where you can add images but you cannot make them clickable (Essential Add-ons - Data table).

I would like to add to these images, links to other pages.
Can I make whatever image I want clickable programmatically?

I try to add via "WP Coder" this code:

```
<a href="/link">
    <img id="xxxx" class="xxxx" src="image link" alt="xxxx">
</a>
```

But nothing happened.

Also the plug-in is giving me a Shortcode but I do not know where put it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: The answer is "yes you can" - search "delegation click image table"

Comment: "Nothing happened" - that sounds pretty weird. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score -1):

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/src" alt="Image Alt Text">
```

Use this to add image.

And you will need to paste the shortcode in the same HTML section let 'say you have create a form from a plugin and it gives you a shortcode then paste it in that div and don't forget to use  do_shortcode();

Comment: Please share more details. The code you've shared doesn't contain anything that links to any other page

Comment: I don't really need to add an image, the image is already uploaded. I need to make a specific image clickable. 
And eventually, where should I use the "do_shortcode();"?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).